# How to search or get info of only remote packages with yum

Tags: centos, package, yum

I'd like to search or get info of only remote packages with yum.
Either `yum search` and `yum info` do not ignore local installed packages.
So if some packages which I'd like to search are installed, they display only locall installed packages with saying `Repo : installed`.
How to ignore local installed packages?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? When yum gives you the info of the local package that usually means that's the same version of the package as your repos have and so the information is going to be identical.

Comment: My explanation is wrong a little. ``yum search`` is not problem. ``yum info`` is only ok (for me) when local version is less than the remote. If the both are equal, or the local is grater than the remote (this will be happen if self-built RPM from SRPM is installed), only local version is displayed. I'd like to know what version is available in the remote. If I installed self-built RPM, that is grater than the remote, ``yum info`` will not display the remote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `repoquery` tool can be used to query a repository directly.

Comment: Thanks! ``repoquery`` is just I'm looking for.

Comment: Specifically, `repoquery --info $package_name`, to provide a more complete answer to the question.